# Shiny variable overwriting

Tags: r, shiny

I am having something like

```
step <- 0

observeEvent(input$myInput, {
    print(step)
    if(!is.null(input$myInput) && step == 0 {
        # do something
        step <- 1
        print(step)
     } else if(!is.null(input$myInput) && step == 1) {
       # do something
       print("Been in second condition")
     } else {
       # do something else
     }
})
```

When I execute my app and the `observeEvent` kicks in for the first time, `step` is as expected `0` and the first `if-condition` starts. At the end it sets `step <- 1`. The `print()` in there shows me that `step` is `1`. However, when the `observeEvent` kicks in the second time, `step` still is `0`. Thats what the `print` statements show. Why is that?

Comment: The answer by @john-paul is correct. To fix it either use `<<-` or maybe `reactiveValues()` makes sense for your usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is basically a scoping issue. Your handler expression - the stuff in `observeEvent` between the brackets, is treated as its own function. If you look at the code for `observeEvent` the `handlerExpr` argument is converted to a function via `exprToFunction()`.

In your handler expression `step` is not defined, so it get the value 0 from outside the expression. Within the expression `step` is incremented to one, but that is only within that instance of the `handlerExpr`, that does not carry outside to change the original value of `step` to 1.